# How do I allow browser in IPtables?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I configured my iptables like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere //(this is loopback)

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

From my understanding, the browser should work fine, because the browser begins browsing through the OUTPUT, which is ACCEPTing everything, but it's not working. Where have I made a mistake?

And my second question is, when I added the loopback rule (`iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`), it visually looks like a general rule that accepts traffic from anywhere and not just the loopback, which is pretty confusing, is there some way to tell it's a loopback rule if I don't know it is?

Thank you.

Comment: Your browser connection is OUTPUT, but what about the server's response? Look up rules for ESTABLISHED/RELATED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete `iptables1 rules will be

Delete curent rules and chains in `iptables`

```
sudo iptables --flush
sudo iptables --delete-chain
```

allow loopback

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

allow established connections

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

allow `SSH` or some different `TCP` port

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

allow `UDP` on port `22`

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

default policies

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Save

```
sudo iptables-save
```

This is it. I think :)